# Hashing to Negative Values

Tags: java, hash

Pretty much the title: I'm hashing a bunch of names (10000-ish) and some are outputting as negative. (table size is 20011).

The hash function in question is:

```
public static long hash2 ( String key ){
  int hashVal = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++ )
      hashVal = (37 * hashVal) + key.charAt(i);
  return hashVal % 20011;
}
```

I dug around and I think I have to do something to do with "wrap around." But I don't know how to go about that.

Comment: if you're not sure whether it's "wrap around", use `Math.toIntExact`. this should throw an exception if that's the case. Also, considering your method return type is `long` why not  declare `hashVal` as long?

Comment: as you defined `hash2()` to return a `long`, why do you use an `int`for `hashVal`? Use a `long`there as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear case of `Integer Overflow`. As you have mentioned in the question that the String may have upto `10000` characters then the `hashValue` will definitely overflow because it is needed to store value around `37^10000`. Even this will fail in string of length `20`.

In number theory,

```
(A+B)%M = (A%M + B%M) % M;
(A*B)%M = (A%M * B%M) % M;
```

You should apply modulo operation inside the for loop. However If you do modulo operation at last or in execution of for loop, Both will give the same answer If overflow doesn't happen.

So make changes accordingly,

```
public static long hash2 ( String key ){
  int hashVal = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++ )
    {
      hashVal = (37 * hashVal) + key.charAt(i);
      hashVal%=20011;
    }
  return hashVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`hashVal` is an Integer. It is most likely that your hash function is causing an Integer overflow.

You can easily resolve this by using `Math.abs()` to ensure that `hashVal` is a positive number. e.g.

```
hashVal = hashVal == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? 0 : Math.abs(hashVal);
return hashVal % 20011;
```

The mod `%` is to ensure that the final index computed is within the bounds of the table (i.e. if it's >= 20011, it uses the the remainder of division to as you say 'wrap around').

Comment: Note that `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: Can be modified into `Math.abs(hashVal % 20011)` although I am not sure how it affects distribution.

Comment: @StefanWarminski updated to reflect this special case.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak No, `Math.abs(hashVal % 20011) !=(hashVal % 20011)` Even if hashVal is negative.

Comment: However you can do `((hashVal % 20011) + 20011)%20011)` For more information [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519845/modulo-of-a-negative-number).

Comment: @SanketMakani Yes, they are not equal. However it might not be needed depending on how this hash is used. I would assume that it's for increased performance when retrieving the data, in which case we just want to distribute the hashes evenly in the defined range, but they values don't actually matter.